# FACEBOOK LOGIN: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook, authentication

I've followed the iOS sdk guide on facebook. But when I click on the login with facebook icon, and im getting the page up. But when I click "Continue" on facebook the app closes and I get kicked out from it.

> 019-03-18 22:39:46.552355+0100 APPNAME[75124:2466803]
>
> ***Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:'*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[3]'

```
First throw call stack:

(

0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111c2b1bb __exceptionPreprocess + 331

1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010fdf5735 objc_exception_throw + 48

2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111b774ec _CFThrowFormattedException + 194

3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111c9a541 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 321

4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111c26c9b +[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 59

5   APPNAME                              0x000000010e481d90 -[ViewController Callfb_LoginService:] + 576

6   APPNAME                              0x000000010e480a3f __33-[ViewController GetFBUserDetail]_block_invoke + 1999

7   APPNAME                              0x000000010e6d2d20 -[FBSDKGraphRequestMetadata invokeCompletionHandlerForConnection:withResults:error:] + 146

8   APPNAME                              0x000000010e6d9532 __82-[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection processResultBody:error:metadata:canNotifyDelegate:]_block_invoke396 + 141

9   APPNAME                              0x000000010e6d92d6 -[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection processResultBody:error:metadata:canNotifyDelegate:] + 1065
```

This is just a part of the error log.

Would appreciate it if anyone could help me out here!

Thanks

Comment: show us your code

Comment: Something is nil. You might have missed a step with a identifiant of something like that. Check all the settings.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will go over everything again. I will upload the code later on.

Comment: Is it likely to be an error in info.plist?

Comment: Hello, I'm running into the same issue as you, did you manage to find a solution ?